# Proof Of Lebesgue's Theorem

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f_1, f_2, ..... , f_n, .... $ is a sequence of measurable functions defined on a measurable set $E$ such that each of them is finite almost everywhere. Suppose that $f_n$ converges pointwise to a function $f(x)$ almost everywhere and also $f$ is finite almost everywhere then.Now consider the sets $$E_n = ( x \in E : |f_n(x) - f(x)| \geq \delta )$$ for some $\delta > 0$, then prove that for every $\delta > 0$ the sequence $mE_n$ converges to $0$ where $mA$ denotes the measure of the set $A$.
$$$$Let $A_n$ be the sets where the functions $f_n$ are infinite then $mA_n = 0$ for all $n$. Let $$A=\bigcup^{\infty}_{n=1}A_n$$ then $mA=0$. Let $B$ be thse set on which $f_n(x)$ does not converge to $f(x)$ and $C$ be the set on which $f$ is infinite. Let $D=A \cup B \cup C$ then $mD=0$. Let $D'= E \cap D^c$, then $mD' = mE$.Now let $\delta>0$ is given. Consider the sets $$P_N = (x \in D' : |f_n(x)-f(x)|<\delta \forall n \geq N)$$ and $$Q_N = (x \in E : |f_N(x) - f(x)| < \delta)$$, then clearly $P_N \subseteq Q_N$ and as all the $f_ns$ are measurable hence all the sets $P_N$ and $Q_N$ are measurable and so $mP_N \leq mQ_N$ for all $N = 1, 2, .....$. Also as $f_n$ converges to $f$ at all points in $D'$ hence we have $$D' = \bigcup_{N=1}^{\infty}P_N$$. Also we have $$P_1 \subseteq P_2 \subseteq P_3 \subseteq ......$$ hence $mP_N \rightarrow mD' = mE$ as $N \rightarrow \infty$. Now we have $$E_N = E \cap Q^c_N \implies mE_N = mE - mQ_N$$ for all $N$. And so $$0 \leq mE_N = mE - mQ_N \leq mE - mP_N$$ for all $N$ and as $mP_N \rightarrow mE$ as $N \rightarrow \infty$ hence by Sandwhich Theorem we get that $mE_N \rightarrow 0$ as $N \rightarrow \infty$.
$$$$Is My Proof Correct??